# 403 Request had insufficient authentication issues while accessing Secrets on GCP within a container

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-functions, google-kubernetes-engine, google-secret-manager

I am trying to access a secret on GCP Secrets and I get the following error :

```
in get_total_results "api_key": get_credentials("somekey").get("somekey within key"), File
 "/helper.py", line 153, in get_credentials response = client.access_secret_version(request={"name": resource_name})
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/secretmanager_v1/services/secret_manager_service/client.py", 
line 1136, in access_secret_version response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 145, in __call__ 
return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 285, in retry_wrapped_func return retry_target( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", 
line 188, in retry_target return target() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", 
line 69, in error_remapped_callable six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc) File "<string>", 
line 3, in raise_from google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 
403 Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
```

The code is fairly simple:-

```
def get_credentials(secret_id):
    project_id = os.environ.get("PROJECT_ID")
    resource_name = f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{secret_id}/versions/1"

    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
    response = client.access_secret_version(request={"name": resource_name})

    secret_string = response.payload.data.decode("UTF-8")
    secret_dict = json.loads(secret_string)
    return secret_dict
```

So, what I have is a cloud function, which is deployed using Triggers, and uses a service account which has the Owner role.

The cloud function triggers a Kubernete Work Job and creates a container, which downloads a repo inside the container and executes it.

Dockerfile is:

```
FROM gcr.io/project/repo:latest
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
COPY . /some_dir
WORKDIR /some_dir
COPY --from=0 ./repo /a_repo
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt & pip install -r a_repo/requirements.txt 
ENTRYPOINT ["python3" , "main.py"]
```

Comment: I would guess an error happens when the code from within your container tries to access a secret versionm rather than code from your cloud function - is that correct? If yes - can you check the service account under which the container code runs, please? Its IAM roles, and check the permisions on the secret side as well, plese? And, in addition, the project id, so the code does not try to access secret version in some other project, please?

Comment: Yes, it's the code within the container that is trying to access the container. I am not sure what all permissions should the secret version should have to become accessible.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/access-control with the lowest resource => secret...

Comment: "the code within the container" is being executed "under" some service account. That service account should have relevant permissions. The cloud function service account is not important if the cloud function does not access the secret directly.

Comment: have you tried with the roles secretmanager.viewer or secretmanager.secretAccessor ? To discard or not an issue related to roles.

Answer (score 9):

The GCE instance might not have the correct authentication scope.

From: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#secretmanager

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` is the required scope.

When creating the GCE instance you need to select the option that gives the instance the correct scope to call out to cloud APIs: [image: from the cloud console]